# Xcode 13, iOS 15 Issues with signing and expired account, any connection?

Tags: ios15, xcode13

So I am trying to run apps on my phone. I do have Xcode 13 and running iOS 15. Not sure how relevant that is.

So when I run the app I get the following errors:

Xcode:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to launch app because it has an invalid code signature, inadequate entitlements or its profile has not been explicitly trusted by the user.

iPhone:

> Your device management settings do not allow using apps from developer "Apple Developer: Name" on this iPhone. You can allow using these apps in Settings.

So I have gone to Settings -> General -> VPN & Device Management to allow the app but nothing pops up. I have also tried signing in an out of the account on the Mac. I have even uninstalled Xcode and reset the computer. I am not sure what else to do.

I can tell you that my paid developer account has expired. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: You need valid apple developer account to run/debug the apps on your physical iPhone.

As you mentioned > paid developer account has expired that's the issue.

Comment: So there is no way to do it without paying for the Apple Developer Membership? I've been running and debugging apps for while without paying, whats suddenly changed?

Comment: Exactly I was able to do this before. I had to add the app every 7 days as the provisional certificate expired.

Answer (score 1):

Tried the new Apple ID but Xcode does not allow this with the new developer account as I was unable to generate provisional certificates. Per Apple, this is only for paid subscribers.

It seems from iOS 15 onwards, it is not possible to run apps physically on the iPhone unless you pay the annual subscription. That’s a shame!

Comment: I was able to run by creating a new Apple ID without developer membership, but I'd like to do this with my own account.

Answer (score 1):

I thought it was because my membership expired. However, even after paying and renewing my membership I ran into the same problem. Eventually I was able to fix by:

1. remove my account from xcode
2. delete developer certificates from my keychain
3. add the account again

When I tried to run the app on my phone, I got the same error message. However, this time my developer account appeared in settings > general > VPN & Device Management, and I was able to allow it.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, this might be a bug connected to iOS 15 / xcode 13.

I found a solution which is to create a new Apple ID and use it to sign your app in xcode.

You can add a new team by going into "Signing & Capabilities"-tab and select "Add account" where you select a team. It does not have to be a paid developer account.

Once you've done this and run the application on your device again, the option to trust the application in Settings > General > Device Management should appear!

Answer (score 0):

I've had this a while, the paid membership expired. Upon renewal, I was continuing to have this error. Turns out my error was that I did not have the "Push Notification" entitlement added to the project - removed it when account went free.

To test if you need to enable any entitlements, you can archive the project and upload to TestFlight. The email confirmation later received will tell you if there are any and which entitlements are missing.