# Xcode 13 on iOS 15 Beta 'Untrusted Developer' error on iPhone XS device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have been testing my iOS app on my physical iPhone XS for quite some time now and all of a sudden it threw an error when I tried to run it saying:

> "APP NAME" is no longer available.

So I went to re-build via Xcode into my device again to reinstall it. But I was getting an error message saying **"Untrusted Developer"**.

So I tried to go to the Settings > General > VPN and Device Management screen to see if I need to 'Trust' my own developer profile again. But it's not appearing on that screen or any other new developer profile for that matter.

Did a bit of research and tried to troubleshoot. One of the solutions I've found and worked was to actually create a new developer account and use that to build and install the app on my device. I does work but I don't want to use another developer account to to build this app as the bundle identifier that I wanted to use was already tied up to that old account. And I have a bunch of other apps tied up to that old account as well.

The other reason why the above solution also wouldn't be ideal as I already have months worth of data in my device that was saved in that app. If created a new build using a new account it wouldn't be able to access the data of the old app built using the other account.

Just to note, that old account was formerly a paid account but now it expired. But I didn't have that problem until recently. So I am guessing it has something to do with the recent iOS 15 beta builds.

I will be filing a bug report for this. But does anyone have any idea or workaround to get rid of this issue? Any information that could potentially point me towards the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks!

I've filed this as a bug on AppleFeedback Assitant. They've reached out to me to ask for logs and the certificate I used to re-build the project. I'm guessing this this a bug and they are trying to fix it.

Comment: Did your profile expired? Check your certificate settings.

Comment: It sounds like your developer certificate has expired because you haven't renewed your membership.

Comment: Does that mean that I can no longer test my app on my physical device without re-enrolling to the developer program?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?  I have the same thing where I have an expired paid account.  If I create a new account I can install on device, but with my existing account I get the untrusted developer error.

Comment: Unfortunately no, not at the moment. Still waiting for additional solutions

Comment: I can sign and run random GitHub projects but not my own app. I have a paid developer account. This is so annoying! Why is this happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 13, iOS 15 Issues with signing and expired account, any connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69079991/xcode-13-ios-15-issues-with-signing-and-expired-account-any-connection)

Comment: I tried the solutions proposed in that thread, none of them worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provisioning profile generated prior **iOS 15** is preventing installation on the new release. Therefore, you will need to generate a new provisioning profile for your app. Try the following:

- Quit Xcode
- Go to the directory of cached provisioning profiles (cd
  ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/)
- Back up the existing
  files to another directory
- Remove all profiles listed under
  ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/
- Launch Xcode
- Install/run the app on your device

Xcode will detect that there are no eligible profiles on your local system and request a new one during the next build to a device. The new profile will be compliance with iOS 15 provisioning.

NOTE: if it still doesn't work, then install the [iOS 15.2 beta release](https://developer.apple.com/download/#ios-restore-images-iphone-new) (Build 19C5026i or later) on your device and try the steps above again.

Comment: Yes! This fixed my issue! Thank you so much. I'm marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: Just wanted to add my operating environment just so others having this issue will have a reference. I'm using MacOS 12.0.1 release version, iOS 15.1 on my iPhone XS, XCode 13.1

Answer (score 2):

I think I found solution for this problem.

You need to remove old certificate from your keychain, after then create new in `Preferences... -> Accounts -> Manage Certificates... -> Tap +`

I hope I will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this issue.

`Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> Manage Certificates -> + -> Apple Development` and then make a new certificate

My situation might be different from yours but here were the symptoms I was seeing. I was able to sign random Github projects and run them on my phone. I also have a paid developer account. I never saw anything related to my app in the `VPN & Device Management` settings on my iPhone and I still don't.

Comment: Didn't work for me fwiw

Comment: I also reset my iPhone (didn't delete all data, just reset to default settings). Try clearing all trusted computers also.

Comment: OP no longer has an active subscription though - unlike your scenario?

Answer (score 1):

XCode 15.0 all betas

Been having the same problem. Deleted the App on the test iPhone and then recompiled a fresh copy to the iPhone and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

**iOS 15 + macOS Monterey + Xcode 13 Seems to have fixed the issue**

After updating to macOS Monterey, my app launches as normal. I will add that I did all the things that other people which might've changed the outcome. This included changing my bundle identifier and deleting my certificate from the key chain and creating a new one. I'm also running Xcode 13.1, iOS 15.1, and macOS 12.0.1.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error on my iphone 12 promax, You just need to create a new bundle identifier then build and then change back to the old bundle identifier. It works for me

Comment: Didn't work for me. I am not able to trust the certificate from iphone settings

Comment: Yep, didn't work for me either